# error uploading image using multipart retrofit

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

I am trying to upload an image to an endpoint using retrofit with the following code,where I convert each of the strings to RequestBody.

```
private void createNovedad(String IdUnidad,String Serial,String Unidad, List<String> Foto, String Tipo,String CodigoReferencia,String  NombrePuntoReferencia,String Quienregistro,String Novedad, String UsuarioAdmin,String Longitude,String Latitude){

        RequestBody IdUnidadbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),IdUnidad );
        RequestBody Serialbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),Serial);
        RequestBody Unidadbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),Unidad );
       File file = new File(Uri.parse(Foto.get(0)).getPath());
        RequestBody FotoBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
        RequestBody Tipobody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),Tipo );
        RequestBody CodigoReferenciabody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),CodigoReferencia );
        RequestBody NombrePuntoReferenciabody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),NombrePuntoReferencia );
        RequestBody Quienregistrobbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),Quienregistro );
        RequestBody Novedadbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),Novedad );
        RequestBody UsuarioAdminbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),UsuarioAdmin );
        RequestBody Longitudebody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),Longitude);
        RequestBody Latitudebody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),Latitude );


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(URL_NOVEDAD)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
        Call<Referencia> response = jsonPlaceHolderApi.sendNovedad(IdUnidadbody,Serialbody, Unidadbody, FotoBody,Tipobody,CodigoReferenciabody, NombrePuntoReferenciabody,Quienregistrobbody,Novedadbody, UsuarioAdminbody, Longitudebody, Latitudebody);
        response.enqueue(new Callback<Referencia>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Referencia> call, Response<Referencia> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(response.code()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Novedad creada correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Referencia> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(t), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is the model that I am using

```
    @Multipart
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("create/novreferencia")
    Call<Referencia> sendNovedad(@Part("IdUnidad") RequestBody IdUnidad,
                                 @Part("Serial") RequestBody Serial,
                                 @Part("Unidad") RequestBody Unidad,
                                 @Part("Foto\"; filename=\"pp.png\" ") RequestBody Foto,
                                 @Part("Tipo") RequestBody Tipo,
                                 @Part("CodigoReferencia") RequestBody CodigoReferencia,
                                 @Part("NombrePuntoReferencia") RequestBody  NombrePuntoReferencia,
                                 @Part("QuienRegistro") RequestBody QuienRegistro,
                                 @Part("Novedad") RequestBody  Novedad,
                                 @Part("UsuarioAdmin") RequestBody  UsuarioAdmin,
                                 @Part("Latitude") RequestBody  Latitude,
                                 @Part("Longitude") RequestBody  Longitude);
```

The problem is that the logcat does not show me any error, but the application stops working. All variables are String

Comment: `File file = new File(Uri.parse(Foto.get(0)).getPath())` Please tell the value of `file.getAbsolutePath()` Also add `if(!file.exists()) return;`.

Comment: This it the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only one encoding annotation is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

`@FormUrlEncoded` - Represents a URL encoded form. As it specified in the doc:

> Denotes that the request body will use form URL encoding.

`@Multipart` - Represents a message with a list of parts. The body of the each part may be of any media type, and contain text or binary data. Doc:

> Denotes that the request body is multi-part.

The error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only one encoding annotation is
> allowed.

means that you should use **only one** encoding annotation: `@FormUrlEncoded` or `@Multipart`

in your case it's `@Multipart`.